# Rules for Transforming List Column Names into XML Element Names

Tags: web-services, column, xml, rest, listdata.svc

I am using the ListData.svc service to pull data from several lists. Many of the column names have punctuation and spaces, so their names are transformed as they're rendered as Atom in the ListData response.

Until now, I've just been invoking the service in my browser and mapping these column names individually, but I've discovered a situation where the exact same list (I used a template to copy the list from server to server) is returning slightly different element names on one server.

Here's an example of what I'm seeing.

There's a column named "$10,000 to $24,999 (Monthly)". On my development server, this column has always been transformed to "c_10000to24999Monthly". However, I copied the list to a new server, this afternoon, and now that same column is being transformed to "_10000to24999Monthly".

It's not a major difference, and it's easy to spot with manual inspection, but there are quite a few lists that will be copied to a dozen different servers, so I'd rather not have to manually inspect every list on every server!

I spent at least an hour searching for documentation, online, but haven't come across anything. (I'm new to SharePoint, so I'm probably using the wrong terminology in my search, or ignorant of some great web resource for SharePoint information!)

Have you experienced this, or do you know what the official rules are that SharePoint uses to transform a column name into an element name?

Alternatively, is there a way to get an authoritative mapping of these user friendly column names to XML names? The $metadata gives me plenty of useful information about the schema of a list, but it doesn't tell me what the user sees for each column name.

Thanks!